# Using html5blank wordpress theme SCSS not working

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

I'm new to wordpress ad web development in general and I am using html5blank theme to custom make my first website as a project.

I want to use scss which was working fine but for some reason it is now not working. I have tried clearing the cache on my browser and cleared the cache on wordpress admin.

Here is my footer.php

```
            <!-- footer -->
            <footer>

                <!-- copyright -->
                <div class="copyright">
                    <p><?php echo date('Y'); ?> Copyright <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="designer">
                    <p>Designed by <a href="/">Bubbles</a></p>
                </div>
                <!-- /copyright -->

            </footer>
            <!-- /footer -->

        </div>
        <!-- /wrapper -->

        <?php wp_footer(); ?>

        <!-- analytics -->
        <script>
        (function(f,i,r,e,s,h,l){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=s;f[s]=f[s]||function(){
        (f[s].q=f[s].q||[]).push(arguments)},f[s].l=1*new Date();h=i.createElement(r),
        l=i.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];h.async=1;h.src=e;l.parentNode.insertBefore(h,l)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-XX', 'yourdomain.com');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my style.scss

```
footer {
    background-color: #99DDFF;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    .copyright {
        color: red;
        p {
            color: red;
            
        }
    }
    .designer {
        p {
            a {

            }
        }
    }
    
 


}
```

The footer scss is all working fine but anything nested inside of footer is not working despite it processing correctly in prepros. So the red is not working basically.

Comment: How do you compile your SCSS to CSS? Is the compiler/interpreter which is responsible for this conversion running? Your style.scss seems fine.

Comment: Prepros is my compiler and it is compiling fine! it is really puzzling me!